# adding double quotes, commas and removing newlines

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a file that have a list of integers:

```
12542
58696
78845
87855
...
```

I want to change them into:

```
"12542", "58696", "78845", "87855", "..."
```

(no comma at the end)

I believe I need to use sed but couldnt figure it out how. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do a sed multiline trick, but the easy way is to take advantage of shell expansion:

```
echo $(sed '$ ! s/.*/"&",/; $ s/.*/"&"/' foo.txt)
```

Run `echo $(cat file)` to see why this works. The trick, in a nutshell, is that the result of cat is parsed into tokens and interpreted as individual arguments to `echo`, which prints them separated by spaces.

The sed expression reads

```
$ ! s/.*/"&",/
$ s/.*/"&"/
```

...which means: For all but the last line (`$ !`) replace the line with `"line",`, and for the last line, with `"line"`.

EDIT: In the event that the file contains not just a line of integers like in OP's case (when the file can contain characters the shell expands), the following works:

EDIT2: Nicer code for the general case.

```
sed -n 's/.*/"&"/; $! s/$/,/; 1 h; 1 ! H; $ { x; s/\n/ /g; p; }' foo.txt
```

Explanation: Written in a more readable fashion, the sed script is

```
s/.*/"&"/
$! s/$/,/
1 h
1! H
$ {
  x
  s/\n/ /g
  p
}
```

What this means is:

```
s/.*/"&"/
```

Wrap every line in double quotes.

```
$! s/$/,/
```

If it isn't the last line, append a comma

```
1 h
1! H
```

If it is the first line, overwrite the hold buffer with the result of the previous transformation(s), otherwise append it to the hold buffer.

```
$ {
  x
  s/\n/ /g
  p
}
```

If it is the last line -- at this point the hold buffer contains the whole line wrapped in double quotes with commas where appropriate -- swap the hold buffer with the pattern space, replace newlines with spaces, and print the result.

Comment: This is a bad idea: your terms are still subject to pathname expansion: for example, if there's a line like `1 * 2` in `foo.txt`, you'll have some surprises.

Comment: OP is talking about a list of integers, so that's not a problem. But I suppose I can throw in something for the general case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution,

```
sed 's/.*/ "&"/' input-file|tr '\n' ','|rev | cut -c 2- | rev|sed 's/^.//'
```

First change your input text line in quotes

```
sed 's/.*/ "&"/' input-file
```

Then, this will convert your new line to commas

```
tr '\n' ',' <your-inputfile>
```

The last commands including `rev`, `cut` and `sed` are used for formatting the output according to requirement.

Where,

`rev` is reversing string.

`cut` is removing trailing comma from output.

`sed` is removing the first character in the string to formatting it accordingly.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) without any pipes/forks :

```
perl -0ne 'print join(", ", map { "\042$_\042" } split), "\n"' file
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
"12542", "58696", "78845", "87855"
```

Comment: or; `perl -0ne 'print q{"}; $,=q{", "}; print split; print qq{"\n}'`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure Bash (Bash≥4) possibility that reads the whole file in memory, so it won't be good for huge files:

```
mapfile -t ary < file
((${#ary[@]})) && printf '"%s"' "${ary[0]}"
((${#ary[@]}>1)) && printf ', "%s"' "${ary[@]:1}"
printf '\n'
```

---

For huge files, this `awk` seems ok (and will be rather fast):

```
awk '{if(NR>1) printf ", ";printf("\"%s\"",$0)} END {print ""}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the column oriented values in a row with no comma following the last as follows:

```
cnt=0
while read -r line || test -n "$line" ; do
    [ "$cnt" = "0" ] && printf "\"%s\"" "$line"
    printf ", \"%s\"" "$line"
    cnt=$((cnt + 1))
done
printf "\n"
```

**output:**

```
$ bash col2row.sh dat/ncol.txt
 "12542", "12542", "58696", "78845", "87855"
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. The extra leading space was intentional for readable output (I hate things in column 1 on the screen), but agree that it is better off not there for later use of the data.

Answer (score 1):

One way, using `sed`:

```
sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n/", "/g; s/.*/"&"/' file
```

Results:

```
"12542", "58696", "78845", "87855", "..."
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplified `awk` solution:

```
awk '{ printf sep "\"%s\"", $0; sep=", " }' file
```

- Takes advantage of uninitialized variables defaulting to an empty string in a string context (`sep`).
- `sep "\"%s\""` synthesizes the format string to use with `printf` by concatenating `sep` with `\"%s\"`. The resulting format string is applied to `$0`, each input line.
- Since `sep` is only initialized *after* the first input record, `,` is effectively only inserted *between* output elements.